# Remove previous UIView before creating another on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a method were I'm creating UIView and it works fine when I call it from IBAction. But when I call the same method again it draws another view on top and I believe it's a memory leak. How do I remove previous UIView before creating another one? Thanks!

```
- (int)showQuestionMethod:(int)number;
{
    UIView *questionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 250)];
    questionView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.93 green:0.93
                                                       blue:0.93 alpha:1.0];

    [self.view addSubview:questionView];
    questionView.tag = questionNumber;


    UILabel *questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 0)];
    questionLabel.text = question1;
    [questionView addSubview:questionLabel];

    CGRect frame = questionView.frame;
    frame.size.height = questionHeight;
    questionView.frame = frame;
    questionView.tag = questionNumber;

    return currentQuestion;
}


- (IBAction)nextQuestion:(id)sender {
    [self showQuestionMethod:questionNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a property which will let you reference a view:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView *questionView;
```

Then change your method to remove the old view and create a new one:

```
- (int)showQuestionMethod:(int)number;
{
    // Remove the previous view.
    [_questionView removeFromSuperview];

    // Create a new view.
    _questionView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 250)];
    _questionView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.93 green:0.93
                                                       blue:0.93 alpha:1.0];
    // Add the view.
    [self.view addSubview:_questionView];
    _questionView.tag = questionNumber;

    UILabel *questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 0)];
    questionLabel.text = question1;
    [_questionView addSubview:questionLabel];

    CGRect frame = _questionView.frame;
    frame.size.height = questionHeight;
    _questionView.frame = frame;
    _questionView.tag = questionNumber;

    return currentQuestion;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to keep a reference to the view you will want to remove (a private property would work nicely). You could add the code at bottom to the top of your controllers .m file:

```
@interface MyUIViewController ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* questionView;

@end
```

Then modify your method as follows:

```
- (int)showQuestionMethod:(int)number;
{
    [self.questionView removeFromSuperview]

    self.questionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 250)];
    self.questionView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.93 green:0.93
                                                   blue:0.93 alpha:1.0];

    [self.view addSubview:self.questionView];
    self.questionView.tag = questionNumber;


    UILabel *questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 0)];
    self.questionLabel.text = question1;
    [self.questionView addSubview:questionLabel];

    CGRect frame = questionView.frame;
    frame.size.height = questionHeight;
    self.questionView.frame = frame;
    self.questionView.tag = questionNumber;

    return currentQuestion;
}
```

Comment: yes, but I can't use this line of code just before creating a new view, otherwise it says Property questionView not found on object type ViewController.

Comment: @DomasfromUK make it global declare it in .h file like UIView *myview;

Comment: I feel this solution is (slightly) more correct only because it shows the property needs to be referenced from the ViewController. Moreover I was able to remove several subviews by removing a single UIView SubClass. And all from the ViewController, and in 2017 with iOS10.3 !

Answer (score 0):

use this before creating new view

```
[myview removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep a reference to the view by adding `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *questionView;` in your `@interface` declaration then call `[_questionView removeFromSuperview];` to remove it.

Or, better yet, keep that reference to it then have a method to reload the info on it and animate it out/back into view (perhaps by fading out, reloading the data on it, then fading it back in). That way you aren't throwing away / recreating views all the time, and instead you're just reusing the same, already created view.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.questionView removeFromSuperview];
```

before adding the other view, remove this from the superview!

Answer (score 0):

Why not reuse the view? 
If you'd rather delete it every time and you don't want to keep a reference to it, you can always set (dirty but simple):

```
questionView.tag = SOME_CONST;
```

And then add in the beginning of your method:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:SOME_CONST] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered, but i want to add a precaution that you before removing a UIView or anything else you should `FIRST CHECK IF IT IS ALLOCATED`. So the removal should be like:

```
// Make property first 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *questionView;


- (int)showQuestionMethod:(int)number;
{
    // Check it it is allocated
    if(questionView)
    {
         [questionView removeFromSuperView];
         //[questionView release]; // Un-Comment it if NOT using ARC
         questionView = nil;
    }

    // At this point you safe to create a new UIView.
    questionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 250)];
    questionView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.93 green:0.93
                                                       blue:0.93 alpha:1.0];

    [self.view addSubview:questionView];
    questionView.tag = questionNumber;


    UILabel *questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 0)];
    questionLabel.text = question1;
    [questionView addSubview:questionLabel];

    CGRect frame = questionView.frame;
    frame.size.height = questionHeight;
    questionView.frame = frame;
    questionView.tag = questionNumber;

    return currentQuestion;
}
```

Hope the snippet and comment inside makes sense.

Happy Coding!!!